# Virtuoso bulk loader and database problem

Tags: java, virtuoso

I am new with Virtuoso so I faced too much problems while reading their chaotic documentation and implementing some code in Java.

Finally I managed to make some RDF Loader but I can see on their documentation there is special bulk loader which I do not know how to implement in Java.

Here is my code which is working fine:

```
 VirtDataset virtuosoDataset = new VirtDataset(virtuosoLocation, virtuosoUser, virtuosoPass);      
 virtuosoDataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
 Model model = virtuosoDataset.getDefaultModel();
 model.read(reader, ConfigurationFile.getProperty(JENAXMLBASE));
 virtuosoDataset.commit();
 virtuosoDataset.close();
```

When I use get method over the Virtuoso I can get the objects that are inserted.

My questions are:

1. Can i see the imported model somehow on Virtuoso Gui?
2. Is this the right way to load bulk objects in Virtuoso?

Comment: Note that the [Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com) provided by [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com) is a more direct path to help with [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com). That said -- for a number of reasons, the [RDF Bulk Loader](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoader) is the optimal method. Other means may be used, but will be less efficient in many ways. I'm not sure what you mean by your first question.

Comment: My first question is ibecause I am using VirtDataset(localhost:111) so it loads the model in some databse and where can i see the ImportedModel on http://localhost:8890/conductor

Also about RDF Bulk Loader can you give me some example of implementation in Java

Comment: Being addressed at https://community.openlinksw.com/t/virtuoso-bulk-loader-and-database-problem/672 ... Summary is expected to be posted here.